# Forbidden on domain of Laravel App- heroku

Tags: laravel, heroku

My app after I pushed my code. I have completely setup my project:

[image: Forbidden page]

I have followed the docs for Laravel app deployment on Heroku and also the Procfile is present which has written

[image: Procfile]

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel#creating-a-procfile

All steps for the Heroku deployment in this official doc

Comment: Does your repository have a `public` folder in the root with an `index.php` in it?

Comment: Yes. I have index.php in the public folder. The message fixed after I changed the Procfile encoding to UTF-8 , through which it identified my Procfile and then the forbidden error gone. But now, 500 server error is coming

Answer (score 0):

Heroku Procfile had encoding which the Heroku server couldn't understand. I changed the procfile encoding (which can be done from vscode). And then, I added it to the git. It works perfectly and my app works after I solved the 500 error (this was due to some database connection issue, which I rectified after changing APP_DEBUG=true for a while and then solved all issues).